# How to find solution for assembleDebug in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

When I try to run run my project I found this messages on run time

"Task 'assembleDebug' not found in root project 'android'. "

How to get solution about this problems in flutter. Error show in given link below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4hyW.png)

Comment: why don't you try backup android folder and `flutter create --platform ios,android .`?